# SQL: Not Like produces different results than what would be Like's opposite

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

So, I'm practicing for an exam *(high school level)*, and although we have never been thought SQL it is necessarry know a little when handling **MS Access**.

The task is to select the IDs of areas which names does not correspond with the town's they belong to.

In the solution was the following example:

```
SELECT name 
FROM area 
WHERE id not in (SELECT areaid 
           FROM area, town, conn 
           WHERE town.id = conn.townid 
           AND area.id = conn.areaid AND 
               area.name like "*"+town.name+"*");
```

*It would be the same with INNER JOINS, just stating that, because Access makes the connection between tables that way.*

It works perfectly (well, it was in the solution), but what I don't get is that why do we need the "not in" part and why can't we use just "not like" instead of "like" and make the query in one step.

I rewrote it that way (without the "not in" part) and it gave a totally different result. If I changed "like" with "not like" it wasn't the opposite of that, but just a bunch of mixed data. Why? How does that work? Please, could someone explain?

**Edit (after best answer):** It was more like a theoretical question on how SQL queries work, and does not needed a concrete solution, but an explanation of the process. (Because of this I feel like the sql tag however belongs here)

Comment: should remove mysql tag and sql-server ( as this is access specific )

Comment: it would be handy to see your changed query as well. And if possible some examples of what you start with, what you get and what you were expecting.

Comment: A good start to investigating this would be to look at the results of just the subquery, both with LIKE and with NOT LIKE.

Comment: If you don't specify a `JOIN` type with join fields and just comma-separate the tables, you will get a `CROSS JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`. That's a **lot** more records than for an `INNER JOIN`. You must carefully look what and how you are joining. So you really need to show your SQL that is not working.

Comment: It was more like a theoretical question on how queries work, it was just hard to propose because the actual lack of my SQL knowledge and scientific language.
So no files, no examples needed anymore. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that would create a difference is to consider this example

```
areaid areaname townname
 1        AA      AA
 1        AA      BB
```

So your first query would exclude both records from the outcome. Because the inner query would identify `areaid =1` to be among those to be excluded. Therefore, both records will not show up in the output.

Using `not like` however would exclude the first record and return to you the second record. Because the first record satisfies the condition with not like but the second doesn't satisfy the condition.

In other words, the first query would exclude any area (and corresponding records) that have at **least one** townname that is like an areaname. The second approach, would exclude only incidences where areaname is like townname but doesn't necessarily exclude all records for that area.

Comment: Thank you! That was totally it. It is just hard for me to see through this much data (thousends of entries) for the first time, it is a bit deep water.
What I needed just is a step by step explanation on how these queries work, and you perfectly cleared that up! Thanks. 
Also I choose this as the best answer because I'm a visual type of person, I like to see the big picture in front of me, and you managed to explain it by first understanding my not that well proposed question, simplified the real problem behind it and showed me the cause of it with an easy to understand example. :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because there can be more than one town in an area, right?

So if there is a town in an area that has a similar name, then that area will be found in the LIKE subquery.

If there is another town in the SAME AREA that does not have a similar name, then that area will ALSO be found in the NOT LIKE subquery.

So the same area can be returned whether you use LIKE or NOT LIKE, because of the one-to-many relationship to towns.

Make sense?

Comment: Thanks, that is it, you are right. :) But Ala's explanation was easier for me to actually understand the things behind the problem, so I chosed that one for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the relationship between area, town and conn are. If you have many towns in an area, you will see the area duplicated in your row set. Your original query simply asks "Show me the areas that are in the following list:". Your query in one-step asks a different question: "Show me the 'conns' in towns, in areas which have an area name not like the town name...

```
SELECT name 
FROM area, town, conn
WHERE area.id = conn.areaid 
AND town.id = conn.townid 
AND area.name NOT like "*"+town.name+"*");
```